# python time.sleep() inside a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I was helping a fellow in this website [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56245558/how-to-make-random-characters-and-numbers-appear-all-over-the-screen-from-up-to/56245935#56245935) and then I noticed something very peculiar and quite specific, it is a very simple question but quite hard to explain, I will do my best to explain the problem.

**I was doing this:**

```
for i in range(100):
    print('h')
```

everything is fine, it will print out the letter 'h' 100 times very fast,
and every time in a **NEW LINE**.

**Then I was doing this:**
I want to print the letter 'h' slowly so I add time.sleep() inside the for loop

```
import time

for i in range(100):
    print('h')
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

And you know what, it works just fine! it is printing it slowly, every time in a **NEW LINE**

But I wanted it to print the letter 'h' in the same line without space between each 'h' like this: `hhhhhh` so I've changed the print from this:
`print('h')`
to this:
`print('h', end = '')` in order to print the 'h' without a new line

and now when I am compiling the code with the new print:

```
import time

for i in range(100):
    print('h', end = '')
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

I can't see it printing the 'h' one by one, I can see all the 'h' letters only after the for loop has ended.

**My question is:**

- Does anybody know why it happens?
- why when I add `end = ''` to the print() it all the sudden acts differently.
- Is this has anything to do with threads?

Comment: I also noticed this a while back. My understanding is that using the `end` keyword won't flush the internal buffer. I think it'll work if you write `print('h', end='', flush=True)`.

Comment: This works as expected in ipython, e.g. the h's print out character by character

Comment: It works! #Ted Klein Bergman